# Modificar columnas de JTable por JLabels

Tags: java, jtable, jlabel

Quiero modificar el diseño de una JTable que tengo
Probé varias cosas, entre ellas modificar el `Object[][]` por `JLabel[][]`, pero no me sirve, intenté directamente en las columnas poner el array de JLabel que tengo pero solo me muestra las propiedades del JLabel

```
    private static JLabel[] DesignLabels(int columns) {
        JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[columns];

        // Label
        JLabel[] label = new JLabel[columns];
        // Define the array
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            label[i].setFont(new Font("Sitka Text", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            label[i].setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, idCellers));
            label[i].setForeground(textid);
            label[i].setBackground(idCellers);
            label[i].setOpaque(true);
            label[i].setText("Works: " + i);
        }
        return label;
    }
```

Ese es el código que diseña los JLabel
Probé esto

```
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new JLabel[][] {
                        { null, null, null, null, null },
                },
                new JLabel[] {
                        labels[1], labels[2], labels[3], labels[4]
                }));
```

Pero pasa lo mismo
Luego esto

```
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] {
                        { null, null, null, null, null },
                },
                new JLabel[] {
                        labels[1], labels[2], labels[3], labels[4]
                }));
```

Ninguno funcionó, lo único que pasa es que me muestra las propiedades del botón, como si le hicieras un Sysout

Answer (score 1):

De hecho, el componente predeterminado de las cabeceras de una tabla es una etiqueta creada por [*DefaultTableCellRenderer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html); puedes accederlo desde la interfaz *TableCellRenderer*.

```
TableCellRenderer tcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
         
    @Override 
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        JLabel lbl = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        lbl.setFont( new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20) );
        lbl.setBorder( new MatteBorder(1,1,1,1,Color.green));
            
        return lbl;
    }
         
};

// Después de haber establecido las columnas de TU_TABLA, asigna el renderer a cada columna
for( TableColumn tc : Collections.list( TU_TABLA.getColumnModel().getColumns() ) )
    tc.setHeaderRenderer( tcr );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo probaré. Puedo hacer lo mismo con las filas?